# Hide label on ui:inputCheckbox?

Tags: inputcheckboxes

I would like to hide the checkbox label.  Is that possible?

```
ui:inputCheckbox",
                { 
                    "value" : component.getReference("v.EventRSVP."+ fieldAPIName),
                    "aura:id": "checkbox",
                    "label": fieldLabel,
                    "labelClass":"slds-p-horizontal--small slds-float--right",
                    "class":"slds-p-horizontal--small slds-float--left",
                },
```

Answer (score 2):

i recommend to use `lightning:input` type is check box [lightning checkbox](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleInputCheckbox), because of `ui` name space going to retired in Summer'21 check out here [UI name space](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_aura_ui_deprecate.htm). more over you can achieve your use case by using `variant = "label-hidden"` if you use `lightning:input`

```
lightning:input",
            { 
                "value" : component.getReference("v.EventRSVP."+ fieldAPIName), // you should use checked Attribute instead of Value
                "aura:id": "checkbox",
                "label": fieldLabel,
                "type" : "checkbox",
                "variant": "label-hidden",
                "labelClass":"slds-p-horizontal--small slds-float--right",
                "class":"slds-p-horizontal--small slds-float--left",
            },
```